# How can I order an array with duplicate values?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I want to order an array of stuffs that may have duplicates. For example:

```
int values[5] = {4, 5, 2, 5, -1};
int expected[5] = {1, 2, 0, 2, -1};
```

Here 2 is the smallest element so its order is 0. 4 is the 2nd smallest so its order is 1. 5 is the 3rd smallest and I want both of them have the order 2. I want to skip over certain elements (-1 in the above example) so these elements will have order -1.

How do I do this in C++ or describe an algorithm ?

Thanks

Comment: In other words you want to compute their rank in a sorted set? How would you handle another element 10 - would this be order 3, ignoring that there were two order 2s, or order 4? I suspect you're going to have to sort the subset of values that you don't want to ignore, then count into that sorted set to determine ranks into a map or similar, then walk your original set and look up each element in the rank map. But there may be better ways.

Comment: Yes, I want to compute the rank. So {10, 4, 5, 2, 5, -1} will have rank {3, 1, 2, 0, 2, -1}. But I don't want to change the order of elements in the "values" array.

Comment: How many elements you do not want to consider? Is there any other element other than `-1` that you don't want to consider?

Comment: @Limantara: I want to ignore only -1.

Comment: @rup: I'm trying out your way. I think it will work. Thanks

Comment: Right: I think you'll have to copy the values you don't want to ignore into another array and sort that. You'll also want to de duplicate that array: that may be easiest after (or during?) the sort. Then look up the index of each input value in the expected array as the rank, ideally via a map to avoid O(N^2) time.

Comment: If you don't want to change `values` you could use an intermediate sorted array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just sort the array, then assign each element its rank:

```
vector<int> v(values, values + 5);
v.push_back(-1);
sort(begin(v), end(v));
v.resize(unique(begin(v), end(v)) - begin(v));
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
  expected[i] = lower_bound(begin(v), end(v), values[i]) - begin(v) - 1;
```

This assumes that all the elements are non-negative or -1. If there are negative elements that are smaller than -1, you need to special case the -1.